# How to apply Z.divide_add_r in a hypothesis?

Tags: coq

I have the following code:

```
Require Import Znumtheory.
Require Import Zdiv.
Require Import ZArith.
Import Z.

Definition modulo (a b n : Z) : Prop := (n | (a - b)).

Notation "( a == b [ n ])" := (modulo a b n).
```

This is a lemma I'm trying to prove:

```
Lemma modulo_plus_eq : forall a b c m n : Z, 
                       (a * m + b * n == c [ n ]) -> (a * m == c [ n ]).
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
Proof.
    intros a b c m n Hab.    
    red in Hab |- *.
    unfold Zminus in Hab.
    rewrite Zplus_comm in Hab.
    rewrite Zplus_assoc in Hab.
    cut (n | b * n).
        intros Hbn.
```

How do I finish the proof?

---

Here is a follow-up question: [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618430/how-to-prove-the-chinese-remainder-theorem-by-some-given-modulo)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? What imports and definitions are needed for the code snippet you provided?

Comment: @TejChajed I just added! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow does not work like this. You should have asked a separate question about `SimpleChineseRemainder`, possibly linking the first question to the second one. Separating questions has some benefits both for you (the `coq` tag subscribers will get notified about this second question, but SO does not send notifications when one edits their question)  and for the future Coq learners (concise questions are generally easier to link to one's similar problem). Please consider asking a new question. Thank you!

Comment: `SimpleChineseRemainder` statement lacks some bindings: `m` and `n` are used but not bound.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I've asked a new one. Is `Hypothesis m n : Z.` the bindings you said?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a couple of hints first: if you open scope `Z` some things will be easier, you can also get rid of parentheses in your `_ == _ [ _ ]` notation (but this is subjective, of course).

```
Open Scope Z.
Notation "a == b [ n ]" := (modulo a b n) (at level 50).
```

You have all the lemmas in the standard library to make the proof simpler:

```
Lemma modulo_plus_eq a b c m n :
  a * m + b * n == c [ n ] -> a * m == c [ n ].
Proof.
  intros H.
  apply divide_add_cancel_r with (m := b * n).
  - apply divide_factor_r.
  - now rewrite add_sub_assoc, add_comm.
Qed.
```

---

We can also make the proof of `modulo_plus_extension` a bit simpler:

```
Lemma modulo_plus_extension a b c m n :
  a * m == c [ n ] -> a * m + b * n == c [ n ].
Proof.
    intros Ham; red in Ham |- *.
    rewrite add_sub_swap.
    apply divide_add_r; [assumption | apply divide_factor_r].
Qed.
```

You can use the `Search` command to find lemmas in the standard library which can do what you want in one or two steps. You just need to state what you want explicitly:

```
Search (?x + ?y - ?z = ?x - ?z + ?y).
```

And sometimes one can unfold notations, like so: `unfold "_ == _ [ _ ]" in *.`, which is a bit more explicit than `red in Ham |- *.`.

Comment: I can't find where to search the lemmas.

Comment: I can't use `add_sub_swap` even I have Export ZBase

Comment: It's `Z.add_sub_swap`, haha. Thank you very much!! It helps me a lot about learning the Lemma.

Comment: You are welcome! :) Since you have `Import Z.` in your file you can use non-qualified names from `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

There is good support for linear integer arithmetic in the `Psatz` module with the `lia` tactic. (There is also an `lra` tactic for linear real arithmetic.)
See the [ref man](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/micromega.html#sec%3Alia).

With it you can solve your goals with one line.

```
Require Import Psatz.
Lemma modulo_plus_extension :
  forall a b c m n: Z, (a * m == c [ n ]) -> (a * m + b * n == c [ n ]).
Proof. unfold modulo, divide; destruct 1 as [z H]; exists (z+b); lia. Qed.

Lemma modulo_plus_eq :
  forall a b c m n : Z, (a * m + b * n == c [ n ]) -> (a * m == c [ n ]).
Proof. unfold modulo, divide; destruct 1 as [z H]; exists (z-b); lia. Qed.
```

The goal that `lia` has to solve is

```
  a, b, c, m, n, z : Z
  H : a * m + b * n - c = z * n
  ============================
  a * m - c = (z - b) * n
```

which you can solve yourself with a lot of appeals to commutativity, distributivity, etc.  It is good to be able to do it by hand, but after a while it gets tedious, and then it is good to have a tactic that lets you focus on the interesting parts of the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very useful~

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't actually true. `Z.divide_add_r` says if you already know (n | m) and (n | p), then (n | m + p). You have a hypothesis of the form (n | m + p) and want (n | m) and (n | p), which is the converse of `Z.divide_add_r`, but that fact isn't true: for example, 3 | 3 but neither 3 | 1 nor 3 | 2 are true.

Comment: but I already know that (n | b * n) and (n | -c + a * m + b * n), maybe I can use them to get (n | -c + a * m)?